# Java How to Control a Animated GIF?

Tags: java, controls, delay, gif, animated-gif

Is there any way to add an animated GIF to a JButton for example and control it?
For example:

- Pause it at frame 1, then make it display frame 2 (Paused at frame 2)
- Set the delay between the frame animations
- Have it stop when it reaches the end (Does not replay)

Comment: What is the use-case for this form of animation?  The best bet might be to get separate image frames and call the 'setIcon' methods explicitly when needed.

Comment: That requires a lot of code for a large number of animated gifs.

Comment: Basically, is there a command that will help me control them, instead of changing the icon each time for every gif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had a reason to break down GIFs but as near as I can tell, Java can access each frame of a GIF.

Whatever your solution, it's going to require some amount of coding.  Whether it's a lot or a little depends greatly on your requirements and your coding skills.

Peaking around Internet, some people are saying a javax.imageio.ImageReader can do what you want: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html

Comment: It seemed to do what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) isn't about animating gifs, it's about sliders, but you may be able to glean something from it.